Testing the Memoryless Property of the Exponential Distribution
In class we learned about the Memoryless Property of the Exponential Distribution:
$$
f(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases} 
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
$$ P(X > s + t | X > s) = P(X > t) $$
I found this fact hard to believe, so I tried to simulate this using a computer.
For example, suppose I have some simulated data representing bus arrivals from an exponential distribution.
Let's say I pick s=3 and t=2.
From here:

Part 1: Find out what percent of times did I have to wait more than t = 2 minutes for the bus to arrive
Part 2: Identify the set of all rows where you waited more than s = 3 minutes ... then, from this set, find out the percent of rows where you waited more than s+t = 2+3 minutes for the bus to arrive
Compare Part 1 vs Part 2. If the memoryless property holds, they should approximately be equal to each other
Repeat this process for different combinations of s and t

I tried to do this in R:
lambda <- 1/5  
n <- 100000  

bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)

results <- data.frame(s = numeric(), t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = numeric())

for (s in seq(1, 10, by = 1)) {
  for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 1)) {
    # Part 1: 
    p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n

    # Part 2:
    waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
    p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)


    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(s = s, t = t, prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2))
  }
}

The probabilities look approximately equal:
     s  t prob_x_greater_than_t prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s
1    1  1               0.81710                                           0.8179048
2    1  2               0.66831                                           0.6716191
3    1  3               0.54878                                           0.5504100
4    1  4               0.44974                                           0.4499327
5    1  5               0.36764                                           0.3689634
6    1  6               0.30148                                           0.3012483
7    1  7               0.24615                                           0.2461021
8    1  8               0.20109                                           0.2019826
9    1  9               0.16504                                           0.1655611
10   1 10               0.13528                                           0.1350997

I then tried to plot the results (absolute difference in two probabilities for different values of s and t):
results$abs_diff <- abs(results$prob_x_greater_than_t - results$prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s)

ggplot(results, aes(x = s, y = t, fill = abs_diff)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "s", y = "t", fill = "Abs diff") +
  ggtitle("Heatmap of the absolute difference in probabilities")


As we can see, the differences in probability are very minimal, suggesting that the Memoryless Property holds true.
Does my simulation prove the Memoryless Property?
PS: I wrote the code in parallel to run faster:
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

registerDoParallel(cores = no_cores)

lambda <- 1/5  
n <- 100000  
bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)

# main function
calc_probs <- function(s) {
    results <- data.frame(s = numeric(), t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = numeric())
    
    for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 0.01)) {
        # Part 1: 
        p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n
        
        # Part 2:
        waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
        p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)
        
        results <- rbind(results, data.frame(s = s, t = t, prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2))
    }
    
    return(results)
}

# execute in paralel
results <- foreach(s = seq(1, 10, by = 0.01), .combine = rbind) %dopar% calc_probs(s)


Simulations can't formally prove things, but they can provide useful empirical evidence to support a particular claim.  It looks like you did a pretty good job with your simulations.
One thing I should point out is that if you are performing this computation on a single dataset of $10^5$ realizations, you are going to get correlations between the absolute differences for various pairs $(s,t)$ in your plot.  This is why the plot contains linear artifacts.
Increasing the size of the dataset will decrease the mean and maximum absolute error across the plot.
